# Gtalk using Jabber web api needs BOSH server or not?

Tags: jquery, xmpp, google-talk

I need to develop a web application using Jabber protocol for Gtalk and Facebook chat.

Something similar to "Gaim" but gaim is a desktop client application (https://support.google.com/talk/answer/24073?hl=en-GB).

What is the jquery api I can use?

Where ever I get the samples, I was able to see that some url need to be given something like ["http://myboshservice.com/http-bind"].

Does it mean that its mandatory for me to configure a proxy server?

I am new to this XMPP technology. Please help me understand the requirements and concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't establish a socket connection from Javascript.  That means that the XMPP connection needs to be piggy-backed on top of either HTTP or Websocket.  BOSH (described in [XEP-0124](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0124.html) and [XEP-0206](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0206.html)) is a way to run XMPP on top of HTTP.

I believe Google Talk and Facebook Chat do not provide BOSH or Websocket endpoints, so you'd either need to run a proxy yourself or use their native APIs.